# Adding support for machine-specific lookups in SQL Server 2012 database

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, database-design, c++builder

I have to maintain an App with a *SQL Server 2012* back end.
There's a database table containing a bunch of
machine parameter settings, one per column.
Each parameter is an **nchar(15)** type referencing
a type-dependant lookup-table, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE L_MachineSettings (
    ID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ParentID uniqueidentifier,
    IsActive nchar(15) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES L_YesNo(Constant),
    OnTime nchar(15) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES L_Time(Constant),
    Motor1_InitMode nchar(15) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES L_InitModes(Constant),
    ...
    and so on (nearly 60 parameters are following, some are ref. the same lookup-tables)
    ...
)
```

Each lookup table is built like in this example:

```
CREATE TABLE L_Lookup_YesNo (
    Constant nchar(15) PRIMARY KEY,
    TargetValue nvarchar(max),
    NotSupportedBy nvarchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO L_Lookup_YesNo
    (Constant, TargetValue)
VALUES
    (N'No',  N'0'),
    (N'Yes', N'1')
```

There are several different machine types among whom, some are not capable
of accepting **all** values of all lookup tables due to their limited hardware specs.
For those, the field **NotSupportedBy** in the lookup tables is filled with the machine types not
supporting a value, separated by semicolons, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO L_Lookup_InitModes
    (Constant, TargetValue, NotSupportedBy)
VALUES
    (N'Standard',     N'144A', NULL),
    (N'Extended,      N'144B', NULL),
    (N'ExtendedPlus'  N'144Z', N'AU1220;AU1221'),
    (N'ExtendedPlusB' N'144D', N'AU1220;AU1221;AU1401')
```

The machine types itself are defined in a separate table:

```
CREATE TABLE L_MTypes (
    Name nchar(6) PRIMARY KEY,
    Comment nvarchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO L_MTypes
    (Name, Comment)
VALUES
    (N'AU1220', N'Basic Edition'),
    ...
```

A *L_MachineSettings* row is allowed to be only partially implemented
so it can contain NULL values, as long as it's **ParentID**
property has been set to another row ID containing the missing
parameters.
Also *child row* values will overwrite those of the parent's row,
so a *hierarchic* parameter structure can be build by creating a *base setting*
and adding only differing values for a new setting while referencing
all other values. If a base value is to be changed, the change "falls through" to
it's *childs* automatically, so XML files, which represent the *final* format
of the data, shipped to customers are always containing all recent changes.

I'm now challenged with the job of **making those column-lookup-values
machine specific**, too, while not throwing the existing database layout
on the heap.
So what I need is a way to store more than one lookup value into a *settings* field,
which would be associated with a machine type. If no specific value for a specific machine
type is available, the *general* value should be used on export. The machine-specific values
should be taken from the lookup tables, too. 
An important thing is: Next to a GUI (written in C++Builder) some users are also
accessing the SQL Server DB via MS Access and those users are not *qualified personnel* in terms of databases  (you know
what I mean), so there should be only minor changes to the existing structure.

My ideas so far:

- Adding a new column *MType* to *L_MachineSettings* to add machine specific options to the *ParentID* setting
- Adding machine specific values via semicolon-separation to a field, e.g. "Yes;AU1220:No"

While the first idea seems simple at first, I fear the collisions with the *ParentID* stuff and the probably resulting chaos.
The second approach will give up the existing lookup relationships, (only breaking that with the lookup-tables *NotSupportedBy* column until now), so I won't accept that change.

Who has some *best practices* for me, here?

Comment: Storing more than 1 value in a single tuple is a horrible idea. It violates 1NF and causes nothing but pain. Do no store delimited values like this. You have to constantly split them into a usable table format so you can manipulate the data, then stuff it all back together again.

Comment: Any place you store a delimited list, consider either (1) breaking it up into new fields in that table (which would be correct if the values in the delimited list do not have multiple values for the same concept, i.e. phone numbers) or (2) adding a new table linked to the original table. Depending on what is defined in the multipart list, you may have to do both. This is the correct way to handle this. NOTE: If you may not modify the base table, an additional table can also be used for case (1).